# Angular dependence of Moiré-pattern arising in twisted graphene bilayer

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, graphene

My question is, if there is any known expression for the angular dependence of Moiré-pattern formation in twisted hexagonal bilayers. The most well-known example for the occurance of the Moiré-effect is probably a twisted graphene-bilayer, as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

I'm asking myself, whether there is any equation of twisting angle that determines the shape of the Moiré-pattern, as well as the minimal number of atoms describing the Moiré supercell completely.
Thank you in advance!